I try fetching my data on the server bisically this signup page, I got cors policy error even I got it configure on the server
I got request policy error, I need some help guys Im stuck just a beginner here!
this is my frontend code using this function to fetch data in the server,
  signup: async (email, password, name) => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null });
    try {
      const options = {
        credentials: "include",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "aplication/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password, name }),
      };

      const response = await fetch(`${API_URI}/signup`, options);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
      }

      const data = await response.json().catch((error) => {
        throw new Error("Error parsing JSON response: " + error.message);
      });
      console.log(data);
      set({ user: data.user, isAuthenticated: true, isLoading: false });
    } catch (error) {
      set({
        error: error.message || "Error signing up",
        isLoading: false,
      });
    }
  },
}));

Here is my backend configure the cors , Im using locahost for now:
import express from "express";
import { connectionDB } from "./db/connectionDB.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.route.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000/", Credential: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hellow Word1234!");
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);

connectionDB().then(() => {
  app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Server is Running in Port 3000");
  });
});


signup:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/api/auth/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000/' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.Understand this error
auth.store.jsx:23
POST http://localhost:3001/api/auth/signup net::ERR_FAILED

"from origin http://localhost:3000 ... has a value http://localhost:3000/ that is not equal to the supplied origin" - Those two values do indeed appear to be not equal.  Have you tried removing the trailing slash?

Typo here aplication/json

thanks and I tried both, but still the same,

You better check your origin... Could you please check in your devtools the value for Origin that is sent in the options call?

@AldrinTorion: Can you correct the typo(s) in the code, re-test, and confirm the exact error message?  I don't see how the error message would include http://localhost:3000/ if that exact string isn't what was used...

@David I already corrected the typo and the URL as well , the error still the same.

@AldrinTorion: Can you provide a complete [mcve] which can be used to independently test and observe the problem?  When I test locally I can replicate the error described by using the values described, but when I remove the trailing slash typo from the configured origin I get a different error.

by the way, it's credentials: true not Credential: true

if the error still the same then you either haven't changed the right file, or, haven't restarted the server - I noticed you app.listen(3001 but the console outputs "Server is Running in Port 3000" ... are you sure you know what you are changing?

Here is the error in the code provided by you.
Backend code

app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));

You have Credential: true instead of credentials: true. CORS options are case-sensitive.

Frontend code 
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

It should be "application/json" instead of "aplication/json":

Port should be correct 
const response = await fetch(http://localhost:3001/api/auth/signup, options);
